# Mongo DB sort by calculated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I have `users` collection in mongo db.
I want to sort the docs in the collection based on the delta between `wins` and `losts`
In the case of the document below: `2-11 = -9`

How do I do that? (I am using mongo from node js )

```
 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "615ebae9f5b277c71b886906"
  },
  "name": "jack",
  "wins": {
    "$numberInt": "2"
  },
  "losts": {
    "$numberInt": "11"
  },
  "lastVisit": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1633852348009"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) doens't allow us to use an expression and sort by it so the only solution i think is to add one more field, sort by it and then removed it.

Query

- on sort you can set it 1/-1 depending on the order you want

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"dif": {"$subtract": ["$wins", "$losts"]}}},
  {"$sort": {"dif": 1}},
  {"$unset": ["dif"]}])
```

Comment: Let me verify I understand the solution. 1) We create a new field `dif` which is the result of `wins-losts` 2) We sort by `dif` 3) We remove `dif`.

Comment: yes, test it to be sure, i dont think there is another way. `$sort` accepts only field

Comment: I will test that - thanks.

Comment: During the test I get `MongoServerError: cant $subtract aint from a string` . It is not clear to me since both fields are int's. Here is the code `const cursor = client.db(DB_NAME).collection(COLLECTION_NAME).aggregate(  [{ "$set": { "dif": { "$subtract": ["$wins", "$losts"] } } }, { "$sort": { "dif": 1 } },{ "$unset": ["dif"] }])`

Comment: you have string somewhere propably because code works see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rkM8fzwtFNo) , you can fix it with [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), update all collection to fix the types.

Comment: Let me double check...

Comment: Yes -- that was to problem. `$toInt` solved it.

Comment: Assuming I want to add `dif`  to the result. What should I do? I removed the `$unset` but got null values.